# How to save term with term references programmatically?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I've got a list of terms which I need to add or update programmatically based on their name.

To check if the term exists I'm using a combination of `taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load` to get the `vid` and `taxonomy_get_term_by_name` to get the term if exists. Otherwise I'm creating the term as `stdClass` object.

When I save the term normal field (using `taxonomy_term_save`) in format like `$term->field_address[$term->language][]['value'] = 'some address data'` everything works just fine, but when it comes to save relations nothing is begin saved.

I'm saving relations as `$term->field_realization[$term->language][] = array( 'target_type' => 'taxonomy_term', 'value' => $another_term->tid);`.

Where `$term->language = 'und';` and `$another_term` is a term which belongs to right field Vocabulary declared in Administer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of field are you using for your relations? Entity Reference or another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the built-in term reference field type, the column is named `tid`, e.g.:

```
$term->field_realization[$term->language][]['tid'] = $another_term->tid;
```

If you're using an Entity Reference field type, the column is named `target_id`, e.g.:

```
$term->field_realization[$term->language][]['target_id'] = $another_term->tid;
```

Comment: but how to achieve mutiple values in this field?

Comment: Sorry @Roomy, typo. I've updated the code